# identify the changes in input values in same component angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to identify the changes in the value of input boxes and fire an event if old value is different from new one. Following are my template and component code:

**Template:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="filters[i]" type="text" size="30" pInputText (keyup)="filterByField($event, col.field, fieldType.TEXT, 'keyup')"
                                                        (focusout)="filterByField($event, col.field, fieldType.TEXT, 'focusout')"
                                                        class="{{'input-'+col.field}}" />
```

**Component:**

```
filterByField(event, field, fieldType, eventType) {
        if (fieldType === this.fieldType.DD) {
            event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
            this.resetFilterBy(event.value.trim(), field);
            this.loadData(null, true);
        }
        else if (fieldType === this.fieldType.TEXT) {
            if (event.keyCode == 69 && field == this.fields.TASKID.field) {
                this.filters[3] = '';
            }
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                let filterValue = event.target.value;
                this.resetFilterBy(filterValue.trim(), field);
                this.loadData(null, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone suggest, how do I detect changes in input values

Comment: I would look into 'Reactive forms' and not use [(ngModel)]. Reactive forms are documented in Angular.io official documentations. Otherwise replace [(ngModel)] with something like [value]="filter[i]" and (change)="filterChanged($event, filter[i], i)"

Answer (score 1):

I would use angular forms/FormControl and subscribe to it to get changes. Adding `distinctUntilChanged()` before `subscribe` should make it so that you get only new values

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.component.scss']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

  testForm = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm.valueChanges.distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(value => {
      // do something with the value
    })
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<input [formControl]="testForm" type="text">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
<input type="number" size="30" (change)="$event.target.value == prevValue ? fireEventMethod() : '' "/>
```

Note: prevValue is an instance variable in your component that holds the previous value of the input field and fireEventMethod() is the method that executes whatever event you want to execute. I assume you meant if old value is different from new one.

Comment: Could you provide some light on component code for this to handle